# Tree of different nodes types

Tags: c#, generics, tree

i want to build a Tree structure in C# where each node is a Wrapper of a generic type T. But i need that the hierarchical relation in the tree is not binded with the type of T. i.

```
Interface INode<T> : Where T: AbstractNodeContent{
   T Value{get;set;}
   IList<INode<AbstractNodeContent>> Children {get;set;}
   INode<AbstractNodeContent> Parent {get;set;}
}
class abstract AbstractNodeContent{
}
class Region : AbstractNodeContent{
}
NodeRegion : INode<Region>{

   // field

   // contructor

   INode<AbstractNodeContent> getRoot(){
       return (i am root)? this : Parent.getRoot(); // compiler-error
   }
}
```

I tried a lot of different solution but i always got stuck here and i cannot figure out what im missing.
The problem it is that in the above function getRoot() i don't know of which type is the root Node so i need an INode< AbstractNodeContent> in return of the function so the when im returning this i have a compiler error saying that i cannot cast from this to INode< AbstractNodeContent>.

Does it is an achievable result or i have to rethink the design? I like the idea of having a tree of diffent type. Can you please give some advice on how think this type of design and how to implement it?

Thanks.
Luca Colombini

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't want to bind the type T to my children/parent to be of of type INode<T>. this is because when i create a class that extend INode<T> i have to choose a T and in that moment im binding all the the type T=choosenType inside INode<T> . Basically i need different nodes that wraps diffent type so the relation between sons and father are not stricted to the type of the node in question. You got my point? Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is because you cannot implicitly convert `Generic<SomeType>` to `Generic<ParentType>`. This is because you sometimes take the generic, sometimes return it, so please see [Contravariance and Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd799517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Try making an interface or abstract class of type INode, with no generic parameters, so you can have an "anything goes" version of the class by referring to this parent.

```
public abstract class Node { }
public abstract class Node<T> : Node { ... }
```

This way, your GetRoot could return a simple Node.

If you want to be extra secure, include an `internal abstract` member in the parent class so nothing outside the assembly can implement the non-generic parent.

Comment: Nice i've implemented your idea and just finished testing it. It works like a charm. Basically i have a class that extend Node for every different Node i want. The children and parent are Node. It was simple and checking your link cleared my mind. I find contraviarance a little bit hard to understand but i will try to improve myself. Thanks for your idea! Luca